# set VLC player options

Tags: arguments, addition, settings, vlc, playlist

I have C# code to play video in VLC player , I want to set video option while adding URL to play. My code is as below.

```
AxAXVLC.AxVLCPlugin2 axVLCPlugin21;
 axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(<some video URL>, null, null);
 axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```

In above line i want to set video output module option as Directx (DirectDraw) video output option.
Is there any way we can set this option while we add url to playlist ?
If yes how we can do the same.

In actual VLC player this option can be find in Tools -->Preferences --> Show setting Radio checked All --> select Video output module[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2yzy.jpg)s --> it has drop down with choices.

I tried with setting
var options = ":demux=rawaud :rawaud-channels=2 :rawaud-samplerate=44100 :rawaud-fourcc=s16b";
and passed this to playlist.add method as argument.

but it did not worked

Comment: stop using axVLCPlugin, it is not supported for years. Try libvlcsharp